# Angular2 - Update values on select box change

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to get the new values when the user selects a new option on the select box.

Right now, I'm receiving *undefined* in both cases `onSubmit` and `onFooChange` and I kinda can understand why, since `b` is only defined on line after the invocation.

I've seen some different approaches to update the values from a select box, but so far I couldn't actually solve this problem.

Could you give me an advice on how solve this problem?

```
class Foo {
    constructor(
        bar: string;
    ) {}
}
```

---

```
foo: foo = new Foo(
    'someValueWillCome'
)
onFooChange(newBar) {
    this.foo.bar = newBar
}
onSubmit() {
    console.log('onSubmit: ', this.foo);
}
```

---

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #fooForm="ngForm">
  <label>Location</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="foo.bar" ngControl="bar" (click)="onFooChange(b)">
    <option *ngFor="#b of aListOfBars" [value]="b">{{b}}</option>
  </select>           
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

In other words: How to get the selected option value?

---

I managed to make it using `$event.target.value` but must be an angular way to solve this.

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="foo.bar" ngControl="bar" (click)="onFooChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#b of aListOfBars" [value]="b">{{b}}</option>
```

SOLVED by updating Angular from 2.0.15 to 2.0.17

Comment: What is `aListOfBars`? Array of strings, array of objects?

Comment: What browser, what Angular version are you using?

Comment: it is an array and that part is working properly

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15", and firefox 45.0.2

Comment: I guess this is an issue that was fixed recently. Try beta 16 or 17

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that is it! Thank you very much.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue with Firefox and IE that was fixed recently

See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8148

Comment: Now instead get undefined bar, nothing changes, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly; If the user selects a different option, the value changes in `foo.bar` that you have bound to `<select>` via `[(ngModel)]="foo.bar"` ; you already have the new value there.

Comment: It should but it's not working like this. I would expect thit to happen but it doesn't.

 I am also trying to force this change with the onFooChange function, but it receives undefined.

Comment: I would investigate on why your foo.bar variable is not being updated. Can you try a couple of things? 1. declare foo as just foo: Foo; (withouth the new). 2. declare Foo as a simple bean: class Foo { bar: string;}